# How can I fetch only rows from left dataset but also a certain column from the right dataset, during inner join

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement a logic where i have two dataframes. Say A (left) and B (right).
I need to find matching rows of A in B (i understand this can be done via a "inner" join). But my use case says i only need all rows from dataframe A but also a column from the matched record in B, the ID column (i understand this can be one via select). But here the problem arises, as after inner join the returned dataframe has rows from dataframe B also, which i dont need, but if i take leftsemi, then i wont be able to fetch the ID column from B dataframe.

For example:

```
def fetch_match_condition():
    return ["EMAIL","PHONE1"] 

match_condition = fetch_match_condition()

from pyspark.sql.functions import sha2, concat_ws
schema_col = ["FNAME","LNAME","EMAIL","PHONE1","ADD1"]
schema_col_master = schema_col.copy()
schema_col_master.append("ID")
data_member = [["ALAN","AARDVARK","lbrennan.kei@malchikzer.gq","7346281938","4176 BARRINGTON CT"],
   ["DAVID","DINGO","ocoucoumamai@hatberkshire.com","7362537492","2622 MONROE AVE"],
       ["MICHAL","MARESOVA","annasimkova@chello.cz","435261789","FRANTISKA CERNEHO 61 623 99 UTERY"],
       ["JAKUB","FILIP","qcermak@email.czanek","8653827956","KOHOUTOVYCH 93 602 42 MLADA BOLESLAV"]]

master_df = spark.createDataFrame(data_member,schema_col)
master_df = master_df.withColumn("ID", sha2(concat_ws("||", *master_df.columns), 256))

test_member = [["ALAN","AARDVARK","lbren.kei@malchik.gq","7346281938","4176 BARRINGTON CT"],
       ["DAVID","DINGO","ocoucoumamai@hatberkshire.com","99997492","2622 MONROE AVE"],
       ["MICHAL","MARESOVA","annasimkova@chello.cz","435261789","FRANTISKA CERNEHO 61 623 99 UTERY"],
       ["JAKUB","FILIP","qcermak@email.czanek","87463829","KOHOUTOVYCH 93 602 42 MLADA BOLESLAV"]]

test_member_1 =  [["DAVID","DINGO","ocoucoumamai@hatberkshire.com","7362537492","2622 MONROE AVE"],
   ["MICHAL","MARESOVA","annasimkova@chello.cz","435261789","FRANTISKA CERNEHO 61 623 99 UTERY"]]

test_df = spark.createDataFrame(test_member,schema_col)
test_df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(test_member_1,schema_col)

matched_df = test_df.join(master_df, match_condition, "inner").select(input_df["*"], master_df["ID"])
master_df = master_df.union(matched_df.select(schema_col_master))
# Here only second last record will match and get added back to the master along with the same ID as it was in master_df

matched_df = test_df_1.join(master_df, match_condition, "inner").select(input_df["*"], master_df["ID"])
# Here  the problem arises since i need the match to be only 2, since the test_df_1 has only two records but the match will be 3 since master_df(david record) will also be selected.
```

PS : (Is there a way i can take leftsemi and then use withColumn and a UDF which fetches me this ID based on the row values of leftsemi dataframe from B dataframe ?)

Can anyone propose a solution for this ?

Comment: can you please add expected output ?

Comment: Its more of a problem statement, where i want to add the matching records in dataframe A and dataframe B, back to dataframe B with ID of that record being same as that in B.

Comment: I have read your ask a couple times and it's not clear what you want.  It seems like you just want a join with select but I'm not sure what the issue is.